# User.admin with Devise ( Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

This is probably a simple question, but as I have never gone through the process thought I would seek assistance. I am using devise for my user authentication in my rails 3 app. Rather than create a seperate model for my 1 admin user i would like to set a user with admin => TRUE.

I have my User DB setup ready to go ( have added Admin column in the USER DB).

My question is how do i create a User so that the admin flag is set to TRUE. Would this be done in the console, if so what would the command look like?

All help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out section [Listing 9.41. of Michael Hartl's tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/book/ruby-on-rails-tutorial?version=3.2#code%3apopulator_with_admin).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, have had a look. so if i wanted to do this in the console would the command be
     User.create!(name: "Example User",email: "example@railstutorial.org",
                         password: "foobar",
                         password_confirmation: "foobar")
    admin.toggle!(:admin)

Comment: I am unsure regarding the admin.toggle? never seen that syntax before

Answer (score 0):

```
User.toggle!(:admin)
```

or as I prefer:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.toggle!(:admin)
```